# How to get rid of widow in List of theorems

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, widows-orphans

In my PhD thesis I have 31 definitions in my List of Definitions. The last definition does not fit on the page, and becomes a widow on the next page.

How can I get one or more definitions to be moved to the next page as well?

In the following MWE Bernard's suggestion `\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}` works, placed after `\listoftheorems`. However, in my thesis the widow remains on the next page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    vmarginratio=7:5,
    hmarginratio=1:1,
    papersize={170mm,240mm},
    total={130mm,190mm}
}

% twee packages voor betere fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

% package voor de laatste versie van het standaard lettertype
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools,thm-restate}

\newtheoremstyle{mydef}
{\topsep}{\topsep}%
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}
{\newline}
{%
 \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\*%
 \thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{\ -\ #3}\\*[-1.5ex]%
 \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%

\theoremstyle{mydef}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\declaretheorem[name=Definition,numberwithin=chapter]{thm} 

\renewcommand\listtheoremname{List of Definitions}

% \usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={thm}]
\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Some definitions}

\begin{restatable}[One]{thm}{one}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Two]{thm}{two}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Three]{thm}{three}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\chapter{Some more definitions}

\begin{restatable}[Four]{thm}{four}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Five]{thm}{five}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Six]{thm}{six}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Seven]{thm}{seven}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Eight]{thm}{eight}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Nine]{thm}{nine}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Ten]{thm}{ten}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Eleven]{thm}{eleven}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twelve]{thm}{twelve}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Thirteen]{thm}{thirteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Fourteen]{thm}{fourteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Fifteen]{thm}{fifteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Sixteen]{thm}{sixteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\chapter{And more definitions}

\begin{restatable}[Seventeen]{thm}{seventeen}
This is two.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Eighteen]{thm}{eighteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Nineteen]{thm}{nineteen}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty]{thm}{twenty}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-one]{thm}{twentyone}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-two]{thm}{twentytwo}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-three]{thm}{twentythree}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\chapter{Even more definitions}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-four]{thm}{twentyfour}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-five]{thm}{twentyfive}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-six]{thm}{twentysix}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-seven]{thm}{twentyseven}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-eight]{thm}{twentyeight}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Twenty-nine]{thm}{twentynine}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Thirty]{thm}{thirty}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\begin{restatable}[Thirty-one]{thm}{thirtyone}
This is a definition.
\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Trying adding  `\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}`.

Comment: I added it here: `\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={thm}]
\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}`, but it did not work. Did I put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Try inserting it just before `\listoftheorems`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. I keep getting the one definition on the next page.

Comment: Please post  a minimal and complete code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I have added an MWE. I have added the same number of definitions, divided in the same way over four chapters. In this example your suggestion moves the widow to the previous page, but in my thesis it does not unfortunately. Disabling the `\usepackage{nowidow}` does not help.

Comment: Do you have the same preamble for your thesis?

Comment: The preamble for my thesis is much longer. It has more packages and all kinds of tweaks.

Comment: You can try with  your thesis preamble, and the same document body as above. First, comment out what seems unnecessary, then to determine the culprit, uncomment gradually until a widow in the table of contents appears again.

Comment: I tried it and expected it to show the same error, but it first gives a fatal compile error on `\loadglsentries`. After I comment this out, the list of definitions displays correctly. Even when I put all of the body in a separate tex-file and use `\include{}`, it displays correctly. Commenting out `\loadglsentries` does not solve the problem. Also, adding a tex-file with glsentries does not bring the widow line back.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know `glossaries`, which I never used. Maybe  you should ask another question, as it seems linked to this package. Sometimes such problems happen just because of the loading order.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give it another try. Or just get rid of one definition... ;)